# Show a label in a rails dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this dropbox with a couple of options. By default, the dropbox shows the first option.
Is there a way to show a label in the dropbox instead of the first option?

```
 <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.to_a, {}, { class: "roles" }) %>
```

Comment: Did you try the selected option?
```
<%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.to_a, {selected: "SomeRole"}, { class: "roles" }) %>
```

Comment: Try using prompt: prompt: 'Please make a selection'

Comment: I tried `  <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.to_a, {prompt: "--select county--"}, { class: "roles" }) %>`, but did nothing.

Comment: Try `{ include_blank: "select contry" }` instead of `prompt`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `include_blank` option.  This should do it, change the text to match whatever you need.

```
<%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.to_a, {include_blank: 'Select County'}, {:class => 'roles'}) %>
```